# Ubuntu PostFix smtp.gmail.com Connection timed out / Network is unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

So, i have a postfix mail server set up, and when i run the following command:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
------------------------------------
Trying 142.250.147.108...
Trying 2a00:1450:4025:c01::6d...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

But when i try to send an email:

```
root@vps:~# mail -a FROM:mail@chatenium.hu *my address*@gmail.com
Cc: mail
Subject: test
test
```

Then the log says:

```
Feb  8 19:11:15 chatenium postfix/local[3680]: 9E6654D6A3: to=<mail@chatenium>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb  8 19:11:27 chatenium postfix/smtp[3669]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.27.27]:25: Connection timed out
Feb  8 19:11:45 chatenium postfix/smtp[3681]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.27.27]:25: Connection timed out
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: The reason for the "Network is unreachable" error in this log entry is likely due to a IPv6 connectivity to the Gmail SMTP server with the Source of IPv4 address

Comment: SMTP doesn't use port 465. It uses port 25.

Answer (score 1):

Your IPv6 configuration is broken. Either fix it, or tell Postfix to only use IPv4.

Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and change `inet_protocols = all` to `inert_protocols = ipv4` to force Postfix to only ever use IPv4.

Comment: after restarting, it now gives error ```Connection timed out```

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You have some (probably external) firewall that blocks connections on port 25 - probably to reduce spam.

Comment: Let me ask my provider, i will comment what they said

Comment: what did they say?